# How do I customise Rundeck with a logo?

Tags: rundeck

I've just installed Community Rundeck 3.2.2 with RPM on a RHEL 8.1.
I've tried to customise it with my logo images with no success:

1. Created **user-assets** directory in */var/lib/rundeck*
2. Copied the images there (png and jpg)
   [image]
3. Defined the settings in */etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties*

   rundeck.gui.logo=logoTNC600x600grey.jpg
   rundeck.gui.logoSmall=logoTNC200x200white.png
   rundeck.gui.instanceNameLabelColor=#ededed
   rundeck.gui.instanceNameLabelTextColor=#000000
   rundeck.gui.title=TNC Rundeck
   rundeck.gui.staticUserResources.enable=true
   rundeck.gui.login.welcome=Welcome to TNC
4. Restarted Rundeck service to no avail: picture not shown in web browser

What have I missed?

Regards,
Raul Costa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your assets at `/var/lib/rundeck/user-assets` path (create if it doesn't exist, remember: the "rundeck" user needs to reach that path). Also, verify the files extensions.

Update: change the order of elements in your configuration. Works in the following order:

```
# custom logo
rundeck.gui.staticUserResources.enabled=true
rundeck.gui.logo=logo.jpg
rundeck.gui.logoSmall=logosmall.jpg
rundeck.gui.instanceNameLabelColor=#ededed
rundeck.gui.instanceNameLabelTextColor=#000000
rundeck.gui.title=TNC Rundeck
```

Comment: I've done that. Regarding reaching files it looks like there's no issue. What do you mean with the file extensions? Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you're pointing to the right file (following the path). I see in your config .jpe but your file is .jpg

Comment: It was a typo, the path is correct. I've already edited my question to correct it

Comment: Check my answer update :-) It worked in that order.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your help