# Is it possible to replace the Rundeck logo with a custom logo in the community docker image?

Tags: rundeck

I am trying out Rundeck using the open source docker image (rundeck:3.3.8). I can ***add*** a custom logo after the default Rundeck logo, but I cannot ***replace*** the default Rundeck logo with my own. Is that even possible? I have tried searching the png file of the Rundeck logo but cannot find that as well in my Ubuntu system?

Additionally, is it possible to change the display size of the custom logo? As you can see from the following snapshot, it enlarges my custom logo quite a bit from its original size.

[image: Snapshot of the Rundeck login page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That logo isn't replaceable, you can add a logo besides that one, take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321722/10426011). The file isn't located on the operating system, is located inside the WAR (java executable) file (at `/home/rundeck` path). The best way to change that logo is to get the Rundeck [code](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck), make your changes, and build your own version following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61553419/10426011).

Comment: And I am guessing the same is true for the display size of the logo, that it will also require recompiling from source?