# How do you customize Rundeck logo via linux command line

Tags: linux, rundeck

I have installed and configured Rundeck but I want to change the logo to my companies logo. Which file do I have to edit or is there a different method all together?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321722/10426011) answer (tested successfully on Rundeck 4.7), but if you want to ***replace*** the default logo consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723172/10426011).

Right now doesn't exist an API endpoint to change that without restarting the Rundeck service, so, the procedure is as follows (probably to automate in a bash script): put the files in the `user-assets` directory, put the parameters on the `rundeck-config.properties` file (in that specific order) and restart the service.